# The use of "look at"

Tags: phrases

*Sentence:*

> It is amazing that his first product does not look at all rudimentary.

*Question:*

I am confused about the use of "look at all rudimentary" here. Is it a special use of "look at"?

Comment: It's not "look at" + "all extraordinary", it's "look" + "at all extraordinary" ... "at all" meaning "in any way" or "in any degree" or "to any extent". *It does not look extraordinary in any degree*.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is being parsed incorrectly.

It's not an example of *look at*, but is as follows:

> It is amazing that his first product does not look <sup>*at all*</sup> rudimentary.

Here, [*at all*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20all) is an adverb, modifying the adjective *rudimentary*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : in any way or respect : to the least extent or degree : under any circumstances
>   // doesn't smoke *at all*

In other words, the sentence could be rephrased in the following way:

> It is amazing that his first product does not look <sup>*in any way*</sup> rudimentary.